Effect of different ambient temperatures on the cooling constant in Newton's Law of Cooling for the same liquid and same volume
I'm currently looking at the simplified version of Newton's law of cooling:
$ \frac{dT}{dt} = k(T-A) $
where $k$ is the cooling constant, $T$ is temperature, $t$ is time, and $A$ is the ambient temperature.
Let's assume we have two container with the same volume of water. One is heated to some temperature and the other is cooled.
Would both scenarios, i.e. the heating and cooling, have the same value for the cooling constant ($k$)?
I have a background in math and not in physics. I know that there are more complicated versions of this equation, but I am sticking to this simpler equation right now.
Would the value of $k$ for each scenario at least be similar enough to make this assumption?

Depending on the initial conditions, they would be approximately the same.

The heat-transfer coefficient $k$ (I wouldn’t call it a cooling constant, as that would be doubly misleading) is temperature dependent.
If $|T-A|$ is small, it may be reasonably accurate for sensible heating/cooling to use the same $k$ regardless of the sign of $|T-A|$.
Put another way, $k$ is continuous as $|T-A|\to 0$ from either side; there isn’t a jump if one switches from $T-A>0$ to $T-A<0$. Again, this applies to sensible heating/cooling, away from phase transformations, for example.
